# работа salt-master под непривилегированным пользователем

Tags: saltstack

по умолчанию процесс *salt-master* выполняется под учётной записью `root`, что, во-первых, излишне, ведь слушать два порта (по умолчанию 4505 и 4506) может и процесс, запущенный от рядового пользователя, а во-вторых, неудобно: при попытке воспользоваться авто-дополнением (для команд `salt*`) оболочка «ругается» на недоступность файлов (в частности, логов, в которые «лезет» за чем-то нужным).

как «научить» `salt-master` работать от имени непривилегированного пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во-первых, надо изменить принадлежность некоторых файлов/каталогов (но ни в коем случае не права доступа к ним!).

привожу имена для пакета из репозитория дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux*, в вашей сборке/установке они могут отличаться:

- `/etc/salt/pki` — каталог с ключами *master*-а и *minion*-ов
- `/var/cache/salt`, `/var/run/salt` — кэши, сокеты и т.п.
- `/var/log/salt` — логи
- `/srv/salt` — каталог с описаниями состояний (*states*) и файлами, доступными по виртуальному протоколу `salt://`

соответственно, команда звучит примерно так:

```
$ sudo chown -R пользователь /etc/salt/pki /var/cache/salt /var/run/salt /var/log/salt /srv/salt
```

во-вторых, надо указать этого пользователя в конфигурации *master*-а. создайте в каталоге `/etc/salt/master.d` файл с произвольным именем, заканчивающимся суффиксом `.conf` (например, `/etc/salt/master.d/user.conf`) и впишите в него строку:

```
user: пользователь
```

готово! теперь можно перезапускать процесс *salt-master*.

---

выявленные проблемы:

1. при обновлении пакетов `salt*` принадлежность некоторых файлов/каталогов может вернуться назад. т.е., после обновления лучше будет выполнить приведённую выше команду повторно.
2. при каждом выполнении любой из команд `salt*` в лог добавляется строка вида:

   > [WARNING ] Although 'dmidecode' was found in path, the current user cannot execute it. Grains output might not be accurate.

   в общем, ничего страшного, это не ошибка. но, во-первых, эти строки «загрязняют» логи, затрудняя поиск действительно полезной информации, а во-вторых, это же сообщение выскакивает и в командной строке при попытке воспользоваться авто-дополнением (для команд `salt*`).

   на данный момент я нашёл только одно средство убрать это сообщение — просто удалить строки, его формирующие (благо, ничего [пере]компилировать не надо).

   они находятся в файле, принадлежащем пакету *salt-common* — `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/grains/core.py` (в вашей сборке/установке путь может отличаться). вот патч:

   ```
   --- a/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/grains/core.py       2016-11-02 08:06:29.000000000 +0000
   +++ b/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/grains/core.py       2016-11-28 16:00:16.122461154 +0000
   @@ -827,12 +827,6 @@
                    if os.path.isfile('/var/run/xenconsoled.pid'):
                        grains['virtual_subtype'] = 'Xen Dom0'

   -    for command in failed_commands:
   -        log.warn(
   -            'Although \'{0}\' was found in path, the current user '
   -            'cannot execute it. Grains output might not be '
   -            'accurate.'.format(command)
   -        )
        return grains


   эта строка добавлена ввиду того, что so «съедает» финальные пустые строки. на работу программы patch она влиять не должна.
   ```

   как «накладывать» патч, я уж рассказывать здесь не буду. чай, все читающие — программисты, и такое примитивное действие должны уметь проделывать.